# Number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please verify my solution. I have got 4 as answer, but the book mentions that there are 6 such homomorphisms.

*My solution:*

If $f$ is one such homomorphism then it is completely determined by $f(1) = a$.

As $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{30}$, $o(a) | 30$. Also due to additive structure, $12 a = 12 f(1) = f(12.1) = f(0) = 0$. So $o(a) | 12$. So $o(a)$ must be one of 1, 2, 3 or 6.

Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ which satisfy those conditions are 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 and 25.

Now due to multiplicative structure, $f(1) = f(1.1) = f(1)f(1) \implies a = a^2$.

So only 0, 10, 15 and 25 satisfies this.

So there are only 4 different homomorphism possible.

Comment: You are right.${}$

Comment: Number of group homomorphisms are $6.$

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes. Due to additional constraint on ring homomorphisms, 2 possibilities are ruled out.

Comment: @PrinceKumar Yes. The answer given is incorrect.